# xcode with modal window

Tags: ios, window, modal-dialog

I want to put this modal window in my app when I press during 5 seconds a specific cell:

[image]

How I create this?

tks

Comment: Use action Sheet [creating uiactionsheet][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223210/creating-uiactionsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `UIActionSheet` for these task (see  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).
To launch it after a few seconds on pressing on a cell you can implement a control in table view's delegate `didSeletcRow:atIndexPath:`. Or instead you can create your own `gesture recognizer` attached to every cell in your `tableview`.

Comment: I need to launch after a few seconds on pressing on a cell on "didSeletcRow:atIndexPath:"

Comment: You can fire a timer or something like when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UIActionSheet for this.