# iOS UI design pattern for consecutive yes/no questions

Tags: ios, ipad

If I'm making an iPad app for a questionnaire that consists of 10 "yes/no" questions, what is the best way to go about this from a UI design pattern perspective?

I want only 1 question to be shown at a time. I have thought about maybe a UIPageControl, but that doesn't seem to really fit. Also I have thought about a self looping segue on the question view controller, but this also seems like it might have its own problems. What about a sidebar with each question in a list?

What is the standard/accepted/best way to go about this type of problem from a UI perspective?

Comment: [Apple's UX Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) might help.

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belong on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

With this requirements, my solution is to use a navigation controller with 1 ViewController that takes 3 params: question index, question content (to be displayed), response (to be chosen). Application begin with first question then go next for another question. The answers will be saved into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If one question is shown at a time with yes/no, I'd use UIAlertView control personally. This way you can use many different dialogs, Here is Apple Developers Reference on UIAlertView:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

If you have multiple selections or multiple choice questions use UIActionSheet. See my SO answer:
[Creating UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223210/creating-uiactionsheet/17223293#17223293)

Comment: I am not a fan of this way because I want the user to have the capability to easily go back and edit any of the 10 answers they previously gave.

Comment: Point taken. You could always persist the data using CoreData from the different Dialogs, but to each his own! Things could get slopping with Pagination, and segues. I certainly hope you'd use storyboards :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem 1 year ago and I used a self-looping `UIViewController`s (I'm not a huge fan of `storyboard`). I didn't see any problem with that. With proper data structures set up, you can very easily allow user to answer/go back/exit.